# Как найти максимум и минимум функции для заданного интервала?

Tags: python, sympy

Есть ли в библиотеке SymPy метод для вычисления минимума и максимума заданной функции на отрезке?

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol("x")
x1 = -5
x2 = 5
f = x**2
```

Необходимо найти экстремумы функции f в промежутке от x1 до x2

Comment: [что делать с ответами на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235550/5741205):

```
from sympy import solveset, symbols, Interval, Min, Max
x = symbols('x')

lower_bound = -5
upper_bound = 5
f = x**2

zeros = solveset(f, x, domain=Interval(lower_bound, upper_bound))
assert zeros.is_FiniteSet # If there are infinite solutions the next line will hang.
res_min = Min(f.subs(x, lower_bound), f.subs(x, upper_bound), *[f.subs(x, i) for i in zeros])
res_max = Max(f.subs(x, lower_bound), f.subs(x, upper_bound), *[f.subs(x, i) for i in zeros])
```

---

Результат:

```
In [29]: res_min
Out[29]: 0

In [30]: res_max
Out[30]: 25
```

---

PS [в следующей версии SymPy должны добавить функции `sympy.calculus.util.minimum()` и `sympy.calculus.util.maximum()`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/16473):

```
from sympy.calculus.util import minimum, maximum

interv = Interval(-5, 5)
res_min = minimum(f, interv)
res_max = maximum(f, interv)
```

<sub>Источник [(с) @smichr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58564948/5741205)</sub>