# Нужна помощь с вычислением массивов экстремумов в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Имеется массив данных np.array, в котором нужно выделить массив из максимумов и массив из минимумов и вычесть один из другого для нахождения значения параметра синусоидальной кривой

```
from scipy import signal
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
x = signal.savgol_filter(np.array, window_length=131, polyorder=1)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, height=0)
```

Как найти экстремальные значения функции в виде максимумов нашёл, помогите найти массив минимумов

Comment: Измените знак элементов массива и найдите пики ещё раз.

Comment: Да, действительно, раз дополнительных методов в библиотеке нет; по тестированию метода find_peaks( ) экстремумы определяются для положительной области графика построения массива значений, что следует учитывать в коде смены знака элементов массива

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаток библиотеки scipy, но в функции find_peaks можно попробовать задать диапазон для параметра height.

Также можно вспомнить из курса матана, что в точках локального минимума первая производная функции равна 0.
Можно попробовать способ, описанный [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1055758/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BC-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0).

Comment: По ссылке библиотека SymPy предоставляет символьные вычисления, это немного не то, здесь всё-таки массив

Comment: Согласна. Посыл был именно в подходе к решению.